# How to fully implement custom right mousebutton functionality for QCheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qcheckbox

When a normal `QCheckbox` is in `PartiallyChecked` state and you left-click on it, it will change to `Checked` state. Right-clicking on a checkbox does nothing.

I want to modify a checkbox so that right-clicking does the same as left-clicking except when clicking in `PartiallyChecked` state the state will change to `Unchecked` instead of `Checked`.

Here's my attempt to achieve that:

```
class MyCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setTristate(False))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            event = QMouseEvent(event.type(), event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, event.buttons(), event.modifiers())
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            event = QMouseEvent(event.type(), event.position(), Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, event.buttons(), event.modifiers())
            if self.checkState() == Qt.CheckState.PartiallyChecked:
                self.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Checked)
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

This works as intended except when you press down on the checkbox > move off the checkbox while holding the button down > release the button.
The custom part of the `mouseReleaseEvent` is being executed while the 'native' part (in the super() call) is not. For instance, the `clicked` signal is not emitted.

How would you make it so that the custom part of the release-event is executed in the same way as the native part i.e. not when the release-event is off the checkbox.

An observation that may be related:
When you press-down on the a checkbox, the box gets shaded. When you move off the box (while holding down) that shading disappears, and it will appear again when moving on the box again.
This behaviour is not replicated in my custom checkbox for the right button. The shading will stay when moving off the box.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant, but I tested your code and `clicked` is properly emitted on right release (while inside the button area).

Comment: yeah, you misunderstood. `clicked` not being emitted is meant as an example of one of the 'native' things that don't happen when released outside the button area.

Comment: But `clicked` is not expected to happen anyway when the left mouse button is released outside of the button area.

Comment: We're skilfully talking past each other here :) It is meant as an example the default behaviour that I want the custom part to mimic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide proper behavior also on mouse movement, you have to override `mouseMoveEvent()` too, but in that case the different button has to be part of the event's `buttons()` (note the plural).

It's also better to let the button handle the state change and eventually override within [`nextCheckState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#nextCheckState). Using a simple internal bool attribute you can then set the different state accordingly.

```py
class MyCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    _isRightButton = False

    ...

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            event = QMouseEvent(
                event.type(), event.position(), 
                Qt.MouseButton.NoButton, 
                Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, 
                event.modifiers()
            )
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        isRight = event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton
        if isRight:
            self._isRightButton = True
            event = QMouseEvent(
                event.type(), event.position(), 
                Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton, 
                event.buttons(), 
                event.modifiers()
            )
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if isRight:
            self._isRightButton = False

    def nextCheckState(self):
        if self._isRightButton and self.checkState() == Qt.CheckState.PartiallyChecked:
            self.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
        else:
            super().nextCheckState()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot cleaner than what I had imagined the answer would look like: something with checking the event position against the checkbox area.

Comment: @mahkitah That could be achieved anyway, using [`hitButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#hitButton), which is exactly what buttons do within mouse event handlers: QCheckBox and QRadioButton override that so that (in certain styles) it only refers to the visible area of the button (the indicator and the text) even if the widget is actually larger.

Comment: Wow, I had been looking in the docs for a function that did exactly that. I straightout dismissed `hitButton` because of the name. I thought it was just a variant of `click()` or `toggle()`. I guess you can read it as "did it hit the button?"

Comment: But it's a blessing in disguise. If I had found it, I wouldn't have asked the question here and wouldn't have known of this better approach.

Comment: @mahkitah Exactly: `click()` and `toggle()` are "actions" that are called to perform the actual click/toggle. Specifically, `click()` (called on mouse release) will do exactly what a "click" is expected to do, and eventually call other things, like `nextCheckState()`. The `hitButton` name isn't intuitive, and it probably remained from very old Qt code, a time in which it wasn't as verbose as it then became. If they had to write that today, they would probably name it `canHitButton` or something like that (and maybe even longer ;-) ).

Comment: @musicamente, in `mouseMoveEvent` you use `Qt.MouseButton(Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)` as an argument. Isn't that exactly the same as just `Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton`?. It certainly works the same when use the latter version.

Comment: @mahkitah You're right, I was still using Qt5 and, in theory, that should have been `Qt.MouseButtons` (plural) for old versions, since `LeftMouse` wasn't exactly the same as `MouseButtons(LeftMouse)` under certain conditions: `button` returns the individual enum, `buttons()` the resulting *composed* flag: `LeftButton == MouseButton(LeftButton) == MouseButtons(LeftButton)` returned `True`, but `False` when using `is` instead of `==`. With the new Enum system, they are considered identical, since there's no `MouseButtons` anymore: equality and identity checks will always be consistent.